# Is there a solution to work with sqlite on Flutter Desktop for Windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I am searching for a plugin or any solution that make SQLite work on flutter desktop windows app, i tried sqflite plugin and it work well with macOS desktop app but it doesn't support windows.

Comment: Sqflite is not available on desktop but you can use [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) which is very close to Sqflite

Comment: did moor supports windows app ?

Comment: Yes sure, moor works on Android, iOS, macOS, Windows, Linux & Web (cf: documentation)

Comment: I wrote an answer, please accept it for other people who need this kind of information

Answer (score 10):

I had exactly same problem and used https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi, it works like a charm

Comment: Yes this is the correct method for using sqflite on windows, see link below for easy implementation https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/using_ffi_instead_of_sqflite.md

Answer (score 7):

Sqflite is not available on desktop but you can use [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) which is very close to Sqflite, according to the documentation: moor works on Android, iOS, macOS, Windows, Linux & Web

I advise you to use it to have a real support on all platforms very easily.

Comment: am trying moor with windows but i cant get auto generated classes like _$AppDatabase is there any additional configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try ObjectBox.
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart

1. Add dependencies to your project
2. On windows, run bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/main/install.sh)
3. It will download objectbox.dll, put it to path your-project\build\windows\runner\Debug\ or \Release
4. enjoy!

Comment: For sqlite, you can try https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi
1. download sqlite.dll from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
2. put sqlite.dll to debug or release dirctory
3. enjoy!

But the db file will be generated in the wrong directory.
I suggest you use ObjectBox.

Answer (score 2):

[drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) is a new package for [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) as moor is **discontinued**. Drift works on Android, iOS, macOS, Windows, Linux and the web

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about that you can follow here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/356

Windows plugin support is not stable yet but there is an experimental support for windows using ffi (and actually the moor_ffi implementation) here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_more/tree/master/sqflite_ffi_test

Comment: i tried both sqflite and moor_ffi and no one of them work on windows

Comment: Have you tried the following sample: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_more/tree/master/sqflite_test_app (note that you have to be on flutter master on windows)

Answer (score 0):

## SQFlite on Windows

### Step - 1

Remember to Download Windows Binary
[Download SQLite DDL FIle](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

### Path

Add the DLL File to this path
[image: sqlpath]

### Code

```dart
class SQFLite {
  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database!;
    }
    _database = await initWinDB();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> initWinDB() async {
    sqfliteFfiInit();
    final databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    return await databaseFactory.openDatabase(
      inMemoryDatabasePath,
      options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
        onCreate: _onCreate,
        version: 1,
      ),
    );
  }

// based on what type of data you want to add your Table
  Future<void> _onCreate(Database database, int version) async {
    final db = database;
    await db.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
              id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              name TEXT,
              email TEXT,
              password INTEGER,
              phoneNumber INTEGER
            )
  """);
  }
}
```

### Initialization

Either you can write this in the main function or if you  are working on separate file You can add it inside initState()

```dart
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    helper.initWinDB();
  }
```

#### [Github Code](https://gist.github.com/ayoubzulfiqar/ea0c22461075ce708a2abbca433a9744)